# How to send mail from the command line?

Tags: command-line, email

How to send mail from the command line?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=780509 may help you.

Comment: You can also use pine.

Comment: You can also install msmtp and follow the instructions described in the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp)

Comment: It's too bad the answers to this are so out of date. It's an important question that could use a good tutorial

Comment: Re Out of date answers: I got [this answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/12933) to work, sending from a gmail account, after enabling "Less secure app access" in gmail settings, in 2020.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try to install [The Mutt E-mail Client](http://www.mutt.org/). Other option is using emacs with [gnus](http://www.gnus.org/). Others options available too... IMHO, you should use more details in your questions, or several different answers to your question you will receive :-)

Comment: Accepted this one since it doesn't require any configuration and is quite user-friendly.

Comment: wait. mutt  - user friendly? the craziest one-liner I've read today :)

Answer (score 176):

1. Install [ssmtp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ssmtp) [image: Install ssmtp]:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ssmtp
   ```
2. Edit the ssmtp config file:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
   ```
3. Append the following text:

   ```
   root=username@gmail.com
   mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
   rewriteDomain=gmail.com
   AuthUser=username
   AuthPass=password
   FromLineOverride=YES
   UseTLS=YES
   ```
4. Run ssmtp and provide the recipient email address:

   ```
   ssmtp recepient_name@gmail.com
   ```
5. Provide the message details as follows:

   ```
   To: recipient_name@gmail.com
   From: username@gmail.com
   Subject: Sent from a terminal!

   Your content goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.
   (Notice the blank space between the subject and the body.)
   ```
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to send.

---

You can also put the text in file and send it as follows:

```
ssmtp recipient_name@gmail.com < filename.txt
```

Comment: It feels wierd leaving my email password exposed in some file on the computer. Is this safe?

Comment: @oadams not very safe. Use 2-step verification to lower your risk, or use a mail gateway that doesn't require a password, like your ISP's.

Comment: Don't install ssmtp on a server with postfix installed. Postfix will be removed. Instead, just use sendmail user@example.com < file.txt which will work with either postfix or ssmtp.

Comment: Another weird thing that I wanted to share here is, it didn't worked for me when I had a long/complex password but worked when I modified it to a simple password, strange but true. I also heard the same from someone else but tried it after lots of unsuccessful attempts to send mail & as soon as I simplified the password, to my surprise, it just worked ;)

Comment: If Gmail doesn't allow your server to access, login to Gmail on the server with command line browser. http://askubuntu.com/questions/460022/using-terminal-as-a-web-browser

Comment: It would be great to have an answer here that wouldn't involve using Google servers. Among other things, they limit the amount of emails to be sent.

Comment: Great. Thanks. This is exactly what I needed to get my notifications setup. @Air I easily made changes for RackSpace mail.

Comment: Avoid exposing the password using SSL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11049483/59087

Comment: can anyone explain to me what the variable `mailhub` is and what `465` represents?

Comment: You can also send with subject like: `echo -e "Subject: Sent from a terminal\n\nHere the boidy | ssmtp receipient@email.de`

Comment: would this work with nodemailer module in nodejs in an ubuntu server?

Answer (score 105):

Most of the time you shouldn't need to configure an SMTP server you can simply use `mail` from the commandline (if it's not already present, install with `sudo apt-get install mailutils`). (Or if you're on a server where sendmail is configured, etc)

```
marco@dagobah:~$ mail -v marco.ceppi.use@gmail.com
Subject: Hello World!
This is an email to myself.

Hope all is well.
.
Cc:
```

You terminate messages with a single `.` on line. That's when `mail` will prompt you for `Cc:` enter the information (or leave blank) and `mail` will then print out additional information on what it is attempting to do, as well as detailing the processing of connecting, transmitting, and receiving data from the mail server.

Comment: I would append the answer to include "sudo apt-get install mailutils" since it is not present on a clean Ubuntu 10.04 install. Also, terminating the message with a . on a single line didn't work. I had to "Ctrl-D" instead. Lastly, the message didn't go through!

Comment: Edit: the mail didn't go through because of my ISP nevermind. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/13072/my-isp-imposes-smtp-restrictions-on-outgoing-mail-is-it-possible-to-configure-a

Comment: Is there a way to send an attachment with this? My primary usage is to send a file to an e-mail address.

Comment: @OlivierLalonde ``sudo apt-get install mailutils`` will install a SMTP server which is ``postfix``, which might be a little overweighted for some people.

Comment: ISSUE : `/usr/lib/sendmail: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
"/home/abdennour/dead.letter" 9/261
. . . message not sent.`

Comment: mailutils will also install mysql!

Comment: -v option not in my install of mail 2.99.98, also had to use Ctrl+D to end

Comment: "cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status" On checking `echo $?` gives me `36`  error number. Any setup I am unaware of?

Comment: Please update this question, it is outdated.

Comment: What happened to terminating message with a period on a separate line? I used to do it for too long to mention here and now it's no longer working. Is there some configuration file that affects this behaviour?

Comment: Instead of dealing with <ctrl + D>, I redirected my message to the command from a file `$ mail --debug-level=3 marco.ceppi.use@gmail.com < ./note.txt`

Answer (score 59):

```
apt-get install sendemail
```

usage:

```
sendemail -f fromuser@gmail.com -t touser@domain.com -u subject -m "message" -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -o tls=yes -xu gmailaccount@gmail.com -xp gmailpassword
```

If you don't want to specify your password in the command line (generally not a good thing to do), you can omit that parameter and sendemail will prompt you for the password... and display it on the screen, but at least it won't be in your command line history.

Comment: Sending mail from a GMail account using `sendmail` most certainty  very handy. Thank you.

Comment: Find a patch [here](http://tuxdiary.com/2015/09/09/sendemail/) not to echo the password.

Comment: I had to specify the port with `-s smtp.gmail.com:587`.

Comment: add a space before a command line to not save it in the command line history

Comment: another way to not display it on the bash screen: save password to a file, then from file to environment variable, ex: `pass=$(cat my_password); sendemail... -xp $name ...` and of course if you're calling it programmatically you can do something similar, ex: ruby `system("sendemail ... -xp #{File.read 'my_password'}...")` also it might fail the first time, you should get an email to that account suggesting you "enable less secure apps" then it can work.

Comment: on Ubuntu 16.04 in 2019: TLS setup failed: SSL connect attempt failed error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Answer (score 26):

You need an MTA to send mail. For this, use postfix:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

To send email:

```
echo "test message" | mailx -s 'test subject' myemail@mydomain.com
```

[HELP](https://serverfault.com/questions/286471/how-to-test-whether-fail2ban-can-really-send-an-email)

Comment: You also need to install mailutils for mailx, right?

Comment: I wish it were really this simple, but unless you're someone very special, this isn't going to work. 99.9999% of ISPs will ignore mail from private postfix servers, because 9.99999 times out of 10 they're spammers.

Comment: this didn't work for me, it asked to install `mailutils` when I entered this into the terminal

Comment: Go ahead and install mailutils. You don't need postfix IIRC.

Comment: @Cerin is right. I needed very simple mailing functionality for a cron job though. As a workaround, if you're receiving via a gmail account, you can set up a filter for the email (via keywords or the from address) and gmail will allow it to be sent.

Answer (score 23):

mpack is excellent commandline way of sending file attachments.

```
apt-get install mpack
```

usage:

```
mpack -s "file you wanted" ./data.pdf loser@supergoober.cn
```

Answer (score 16):

Install the package `sendmail` then type

```
sendmail -t receiver@example
```

then write your email
then press Ctrl+D

Answer (score 11):

```
mail -s "subjet" -a "attchedfile_name" someone@dest_email.com
```

or

```
cat "afile" | mail -s "subject" someone@dest_email.com
```

Comment: just to add for easy testing: echo "Hello world!" | mail -s "Hello" mail@example.org

Comment: If someone doesn't have the mail command, just run: `sudo apt-get install mailutils` in Ubuntu/Debian or `yum install mailx` in CentOS/Redhat

Answer (score 10):

#### You can send an email from the command line with **TelNet** or **NetCat**.

Everything is explained [**here**](http://hanoo.org/index.php?article=send-email-command-line).

```
hanoo@hp_laptop% nc 127.0.0.1 25
220 hp_laptop.localdomain ESMTP Postfix
EHLO man
250 hp_laptop.localdomain
MAIL FROM: <netcat@postfix.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: <target@host.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
This is the body of my mail,
this is the second line...
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9C12E7F404
```

Comment: It's a little hard to use SSL when using this method ;)

Comment: @iX3 just use `swaks` and you're fine with SSL/TLS, too ;-)

Comment: Or `openssl s_client -starttls smtp ...`

Answer (score 7):

If you try to send e-mail from a system, whitch does not run an own e-mail-server (i. e. desktop system), you need to install something like [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) or [esmtp](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/), which forward your local mail to a "real" mail server.

As command line tools you can install mail or mailx (packages mailutils, heirloom-mailx or bsd-mailx). If you need attachments try biabam.

Comment: I like bsd-mailx for the -E command and cronjobs

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install sharutils mailutils
uuencode filename filename | mail user@example.com
```

where `filename` is the same: it stands for input file and remote file.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install sharutils` for `uuencode`

Comment: mailutils installs mysql! oO

Answer (score 5):

I have never tried it but there is a `mail` command that can send mail. See [man mail](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mail).

To test local email:

```
echo message | mail username@localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
mail name@mailserver.com -s "Attached file" <<EOF                 
Hi

~| uuencode $HOME/filename.txt filename.txt

EOF
```

It works with [GNU Mailutils](http://mailutils.org/manual/html_section/mail.html), check the website for more information.

Answer (score 2):

**Run**:

```
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
sudo -H gedit /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

The following needs to be added there:

```
# The user that gets all the mails (UID < 1000, usually the admin)
root=yourusernameofgmail@gmail.com

# The mail server (where the mail is sent to), both port 465 or 587 should be acceptable
# See also https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78799
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# The address where the mail appears to come from for user authentication.
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# Use SSL/TLS before starting negotiation
UseTLS=Yes
UseSTARTTLS=Yes

# Username/Password
AuthUser=yourusernameofgmail
AuthPass=yourGmailPassowrd
AuthMethod=LOGIN

# Email 'From header's can override the default domain?
FromLineOverride=yes
```

**Run**:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/ssmtp/revaliases
```

Enter there:

```
root:yourusernameofgmail@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

**Enable *"less secure apps"* on Gmail:**
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

**Test it by running the following on terminal:**

```
echo "Body of mail is abc" | mail -s "Subject is xyz" "someusername@gmail.com"`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use cURL. Take a file like this:

```
From: Sunday <sunday@gmail.com>
To: Monday <monday@gmail.com>
Subject: Tuesday

Wednesday
```

and send it:

```
curl \
--netrc \
--mail-rcpt monday@gmail.com \
--upload-file a.txt \
smtps://smtp.gmail.com
```

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another quite simple yet interesting way to do, provided by AWS ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html))

So, you need to prepare this text file, save it as `input.txt`. Please remember to change the values:

- Replace example.com with your sending domain.
- Replace Base64EncodedSMTPUserName with your base64-encoded SMTP username.
- Replace Base64EncodedSMTPPassword with your base64-encoded SMTP password.
- Replace sender@example.com with the email address you are sending from. This identity must be verified.
- Replace recipient@example.com with the destination email address. If your Amazon SES account is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.

  ```
  EHLO example.com
  AUTH LOGIN
  Base64EncodedSMTPUserName
  Base64EncodedSMTPPassword
  MAIL FROM: sender@example.com
  RCPT TO: recipient@example.com
  DATA
  From: Sender Name <sender@example.com>
  To: recipient@example.com
  Subject: Amazon SES SMTP Test

  This message was sent using the Amazon SES SMTP interface.
  .
  QUIT
  ```
- To send using explicit SSL over port 587 – Enter the following command:

  ```
  openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect smtp-server-endpoint:587 < input.txt
  ```
- To send using implicit SSL over port 465 – Enter the following command:

  ```
  openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -connect smtp-server-endpoint:465 < input.txt
  ```

**Impatient SMTP servers**

If you face `Client host rejected: Improper use of SMTP command pipelining` errors, try waiting for the responses:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect smtp.example.com:587 < \
    <(
        echo "EHLO foo.tld"
        sleep 2
        echo "AUTH LOGIN"
        sleep 2
        echo "Base64EncodedSMTPUserName"
        sleep 2
        echo "Base64EncodedSMTPPassword"
        sleep 2
        echo "MAIL FROM: sender@example.com"
        sleep 2
        echo "RCPT TO: recipient@example.com"
        sleep 2
        echo "DATA"
        sleep 2
        echo "Sender Name <sender@example.com>"
        echo "recipient@example.com"
        echo "Subject: Test"
        echo ""
        echo "Lorem Ipsum"
        echo "."
        echo "QUIT"
    )
```