# My ISP imposes SMTP restrictions on outgoing mail, is it possible to configure a system wide SMTP address?

Tags: configuration, smtp

My ISP imposes SMTP restrictions on outgoing mail, is it possible to configure a system wide SMTP address to use, instead of having to configure each mail client individually?

Comment: I having problems with the mail command. How were you able to tell it was an isp block?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

- Open up `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
- Replace `relayhost =` by `relayhost = relay.your-isp.com` where `relay.your-isp.com` is your ISP's SMTP server.

Comment: That'll work if postfix is your installed MTA, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the commonly used MTAs in linux distributions can be configured to send all outgoing mail via a so called 'smarthost'.

In the case of postfix, that's via the `relayhost` option as described in @OlivierLalonde's answer; however, every mail server has its own way of configuring things, and until and unless you specify which one you're using it's hard to help you further than this.

You can try `telnet localhost 25` and look at the greeting string, that should normally tell you what program's doing the answering.