# How do I install these printing and mail related utilities?

Tags: server, software-installation, software-recommendation, mail

My job wants me to install the following utilities on our Ubuntu server:

- `lp`
- `lpstat`
- `cancel`
- `mail`

I have no idea how to do it.

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use `lp`, `lpstat` and `cancel`, you need to install and configure a printer.

In the process of installing the printer, you're going to install `cups-client`, which contains these utilities.

The `mail` program is in `mailutils`

To install both of these, type

```
sudo apt-get install cups-client
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Afterwards, you may want to

- [set up a Print server](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/cups.html)
- [set up a Mail server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line)

Comment: It is important to note that `mail` itself won't work without a mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `cups-client` and `mailutils` packages.

You can do this from GUI (System → *Administration* → *Synaptic Package Manager*) or using the command line (terminal) with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install cups-client mailutils
```