# Sending mail without domain name

Tags: email, mail

We have a server, we are using this for backups and other cronjobs. I would like to send mail to the users when one of their cronjobs or backups has ended. Is it possible to do this if I don't have a domain name?

Comment: use a regular mail service? like gmail?

Comment: Or just buy a domain name, they aren't expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to send emails without having a domain name, if you currently make use of Gmail you can use your existing Gmail account to send emails as desired. This is a great tutorial which can help you configure it all:

http://mattlong.posterous.com/enable-cron-emails-using-gmail-on-ubuntu

## UPDATE for link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130423104300/http://mattlong.posterous.com/enable-cron-emails-using-gmail-on-ubuntu

This is one example of how to do it, you can use other email accounts it is not restricted to Gmail, but I believe this to be the most common.

Comment: Your link is dead. Any chance you could find a new one? Or even better, incorporate the steps into the answer itself :)

Comment: Here is the archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20130423104300/http://mattlong.posterous.com/enable-cron-emails-using-gmail-on-ubuntu

Comment: did not work for me. after setting up exim4 it gave error "grep: /etc/inetd.conf: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 11):

> Is it possible to do this if I don't have a domain name?

The short answer is **Yes**. You don't need a domain name to send email and my servers regularly send me emails (through `postfix` - you do need a MTA) about things from their hostname and my computer does the same. I'm constantly getting emails from `root@bert` (`bert` is my hostname).

The "problem" is that the emails might be blocked without a fully-qualified domain name because lots of anti-spam stuff relies on FQDNs to score emails' spamminess. I personally don't have any problems sending mail to myself on Gmail but you might have problems with Gmail or other providers.

The most professional solution would be to get a proper domain and set things up but if don't want to stretch the $10 or so, you can get a free email account with Google, Hotmail, etc. and most of them will let you send email via SMTP. And then [`postfix` can relay those emails](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/11/11/relaying-postfix-smtp-via-smtpgmailcom/)

The email sending is solved here: [How to send mail from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line)

Comment: The spam problem seems worse if your recipients use Outlook.  I find that my internal-only emails from servers get flagged as spam, but also that Outlook will not allow white-listing of email addresses without a domain name (it says they are invalid)

Comment: What about through a dynamic DNS provider? They can provide a free domain (well their domain) connecting your home IP address. Although I read that receiving emails will be unreliable, while sending emails will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to send an email without the complexity is to use the sendemail package. Assuming your server can see some kind of SMTP account, it's a breeze.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/sendEmail.1.html