# Shell script that checks user activity and sends an email to the user in case of inactivity

Tags: bash, scripts, command-line

I need to check user activity under Linux (Ubuntu) and after 10 minutes I need to alert the user over email.

By inactivity, I'm referring to CPU usage of the processes that user is running. I tried using "ps -a" to get the user proceses, but I don't know how to check for specific CPU usage

Answer (score 2):

As your question is not terribly specific I can only guess at what you mean. If by user activity you mean keyboard or mouse, then this can by implemented in a few different ways. In a bash script you can use the command xprintidle (in the standard repositories). Then, if you have the appropriate email [set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line), you can use e.g. the mail command to send the email.

Alternatively, after detecting the timeout you can also call e.g. a python script and get it to send and email using standard protocols and you favorite email account e.g. gmail. You can read about that e.g. [here](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-through-gmail-with-python/) For sompleteness sake, I have pasted the code example from that page here:

```
import smtplib

fromaddr = 'fromuser@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'touser@gmail.com'
msg = 'There was a terrible error that occured and I wanted you to know!'

# Credentials (if needed)
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

# The actual mail send
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

If you want, you can also keep the entire thing in python. The standard recipe is to use the ctypes module to access libX. I have previously tried implementing one of these recipes and (with the exception of sometime having to replace a few of the lib paths) it works really well. I wont paste those code examples here as they are huge and found on several websites e.g. [here](http://informatiq.org/content/python-monitor-x-idle-time), if you want more search for "python x idle time" maybe add ubuntu or linux.

If you have more specific questions to one of these approaches let me know and please also elaborate a little more in your question.

Comment: I edit the question with more information. I think "xprintidle" can be a good solution, since checking for idle time is more straight forward than checking for CPU usage. But, I need a solution without installing other binaries.

Comment: In that case how about the Python/ctypes examples I linked to?