# Ubuntu VPS Automatic Backup Script

Tags: server, backup, cron, vps

> > Can anyone tell me how to create a **backup script** for Ubuntu VPS which is used as a **webserver**.
> >
> > I also want to add it as a cron job so that it runs automatically every day midnight at **12:00AM**

### Programs which i use in my VPS :

- Apache2
- php5
- MySQL
- phpMyAdmin
- sites-enabled
- SSL

***Thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using `rsync` to perform the actual backup to your other server:

```
man rsync
```

You will need to know *exactly* what data you would like to backup, though. Just from the list of programs (if you are using the vanilla directories), you will want to at least backup:

- /var/lib/apache2
- /var/log/apache2
- /var/www
- /etc/apache2
- /var/lib/mysql

For scheduling the backup process, you can look into `crontab`:

```
man crontab
```

Tips:

- Try to isolate the backup process to a specific user, then give it read access to the backup directories. I would *highly* recommend not using the `root` user to backup your data.
- Make sure that your backup script is executable (`chmod +x /my/backupscript`)
- `rsync` runs over SSH, so whatever is initiating the backup will need SSH access (`man ssh-keygen`).
- Depending on what kind of data you are hosting, you will want to make sure and stop all processes that are using the backup directories. I would definitely recommend stopping MySQL at a minimum (`service mysqld stop`).
- It's more efficient to make a local, compressed (`man tar`) backup of the data (for example, to `/backups/mydata_$(date +%s).tgz`), then `rsync` the local backup to your other server. Actively `rsync`ing the actual directories could lead to extended downtime on your db as your dataset grows.

Comment: can i email the backups as an attachment after every backup?

Comment: @MidhunVarghese do you mean email the actual backup? If it's small enough in size, then you probably could. If you want your server to send email, you can find a simple overview [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line).