# Owncloud Installation problems

Tags: juju, owncloud-server

I am having a lot of trouble getting started with an owncloud installation.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 server (with Lamp).

The info on the owncloud website seems to produce an error.
I tried to use juju but even `sudo-add-apt-repository` (from get started on https://jujucharms.com/get-started gives a `need a repository as argument` message).

Basically what is the easiest way to get owncloud installed and I admit I am totally new at this and that the command line "frightens" me?

Comment: no need to be frightend of the commandline :) ! And please mark drinxys anwers below as 'accepted' if it worked out for you. best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Modified from owncloud.org:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list
```

Then paste this into that screen

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.04/ /
```

Then update repos and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

That should install all the dependencies it needs etc also.

Comment: I can't actually work out how to access owncloud.org - I have read http://askubuntu.com/questions/460022/using-terminal-as-a-web-browser and tried w3m and lynx but get "unable to fetch some archives"

Comment: did you try to install as per my answer? Also I rarely use terminal to browse sites etc. I generally have an SSH session open to the server I am working on from an Ubuntu desktop. If I need to look for an answer online i use good old firefox and copy/paste commands if i need to.

Comment: Yes - nothing seems to happen. When I first login I have paul@ubuntu:~$ at that prompt I type the first line you gave me and it changes to ">" only. I then type the next two lines, nothing happens and I've still got ">" with a blinking _

Comment: @PaulCutler I've updated my answer. It should do the same thing but using a slightly different method.

Comment: After the first line sudo nano.... I get a screen with "GNU nano 2.2.6" at the top and a flashing "_" At that flashing cursor I typed your second line deb http://... etc - nothing has happened after that - still just a flashing cursor. I am feeling really inadequate here and totally incapable of doing any of my own problem solving (a bit frustrating - for both of us)!

Comment: So when you're at the screen with the flashing cursor, that's just a text editor. You should be able to paste (ctrl+shift+v) the deb http.... line into the that screen. To save you use ctrl+o and to then exit you use ctrl+x.

Comment: Oh and don't feel inadequate. I've been in the industry many years, so I probably make it feel easy. My first time using bash / linux command line was very intimidating. I had no idea what I was doing, and wanted nothing to do with it ever again!

Comment: I can't cut and paste in the text editor - I only have server configured on this computer and I am accessing websites (reading this post) from another desktop. I have typed the URL provided. I am started to query whether I am connected to internet - ping google.com.au (or anything else) yields "unknown host" and I did tick the install DNS in the options when I installed Ubuntu server 14.04

Comment: what does "deb" do at the start of that line? Some other tutorials on net use "wget" - when I tried that I got "unable to resolve host address"

Comment: What should happen after I've typed the "deb http://...." line?

Comment: after you type deb http://... you save and exit as per my previous comments. Regarding the dns issue that's a whole other problem, you'd be best starting a new question for that.

Comment: I did save and exit the text. Then "sudo apt-get update" results in "malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list (dist) [new line] "the list of sources could not be read"

Comment: my suspicions about internet were correct - I reinstalled Ubuntu server with an ethernet cable - ping [any URL] now works and so does your suggestion above. Such a dumb problem that's occupied a good proportion of my free time this week (and yours as well) - REALLY appreciate your patient assistance! Now to figure out how to configure owncloud!!