# Apticron does not send any emails

Tags: apticron

I've installed Apticron a few days ago, but I'm not getting any emails even though I've edited `/etc/apticron/apticron.conf` and changed `EMAIL= MY@MAIL.COM`.

Does anyone have any ideas? I got Mailx installed and working properly and I'm able to send mails using Mailx, but for some reason I can't get it done with Apticron.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The solution:

Edit this file

```
nano /etc/cron.d/apticron
```

and replace this line

```
10 * * * * root if test -x /usr/sbin/apticron; then /usr/sbin/apticron --cron; else true; fi
```

to like this:

```
10 * * * * root if test -x /usr/sbin/apticron; then /usr/sbin/apticron; else true; fi
```

I'm not sure why, but it works without

> --cron

parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it did not work due to [greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting_(email)) by recipient MX server.

> A mail transfer agent (MTA) using greylisting will "temporarily reject" any email from a sender it does not recognize. If the mail is legitimate, the originating server will try again after a delay, and if sufficient time has elapsed, the email will be accepted.

So it is better to test that outgoing mail reaches your notification address before expecting `apticron` to work.

I used `mail` command as described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/12939).

> NOTE: it might be a good idea to use some test service like [mail-tester.com](https://mail-tester.com) first in a hope to not get your dedicated IP instantly flagged by real e-mail provider like Google or the one that serves your recipient. It is just a thought though, I have no idea if such test services actually work that way, but it would be a logical assumption.

By reading auto-reply from `mail` I saw that my e-mail was not delivered with a mention of

```
Sorry, the service is currently unavailable. Please come back later
```

If you simply remove `--cron` parameter `apticron` will execute every hour instead of once per day. Which probably results in bypassing [greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting_(email)) protection but does not fix real issues. E.g. my test e-mails ended up in spam.