# configuring sendmail on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sendmail

I'm trying to configure the sendmail on my ubuntu, the following should install the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail sendmail-cf m4
```

But then when I'm changing the sendmail.mc file how I should compile it to see the changes in `sendmail.cf` file ??

[This tutorial](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-and-setup-sendmail-on-ubuntu/) suggests the `make` command :

```
cd /etc/mail
make
```

but then the changes are not reflect in my `sendmail.cf` command.
Also some suggests that :

```
m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

But then I'm getting the error :

```
m4:/etc/mail/sendmail.mc:10: cannot open `/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4': No such file or directory
```

So I don't know how to compile the `sendmail.mc` file !!
And as I mentioned I have installed the `sendmail`, `sendmail-cf` and `m4` packages.

Comment: if you would like to try other method to send email through ubuntu terminal you can look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2):

I have given up on sendmail and discovered that msmtp is much easier to install. My old server was evidently linking sendmail to msmtp. `sudo apt install msmtp` I put settings in /etc/msmtprc:

```
defaults

timeout 15
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_certcheck on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account default

host EMAIL_SMTP_SERVER
port 587
auto_from off
from ACCOUNT@DOMAIN

auth on
user ACCOUNT@DOMAIN
password PASSWORD
```

Test it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/msmtp /usr/bin/sendmail
echo "Subject: Sendmail (MSMTP) Test" | sendmail -v recipient@domain.com
```